# How do i make a leaderboard for my invite tracker discord bot? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to add a leaderboard to my invite tracker discord.py bot. Here is my invite code.

```
    @client.command()
async def invites(ctx, user = None):
  if user == None:
    totalInvites = 0
    for i in await ctx.guild.invites():
        if i.inviter == ctx.author:
            totalInvites += i.uses
    await ctx.send(f"You've invited {totalInvites} member{'' if totalInvites == 1 else 's'} to the server!")
  else:
    totalInvites = 0
    for i in await ctx.guild.invites():
       member = ctx.message.guild.get_member_named(user)
       if i.inviter == member:
         totalInvites += i.uses
    await ctx.send(f"{member} has invited {totalInvites} member{'' if totalInvites == 1 else 's'} to the server!")
```

Any help would be usefull.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please include a specific programming question that you are looking to have answered. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, consider using a `membership` operator (`is`, `is not`) to compare to None instead of `comparison` operator (`==`, `!=`, `>=`, `<=`)

`user` will never be resolved to a `Member` object, because you haven't type hinted to `discord.Member` (do note, by doing this you won't have to use `Guild.get_member_named`)

You also have a lot of useless code, try keeping your code short and sweet usually. Those if else conditions weren't needed. You can re0assign user to `user or ctx.author` in the first line of the code, and then just continue with the normal code.

`None` is implicitly a `falsey` value, so if user was None, it was assign user to `ctx.author`, on the contrary if it was an actual Member, then it would stay the same.

A few other things can be done to write short and sweet code as well. Doing all of the above, you would get something like:

```py
@client.command()
async def invites(ctx: commands.Context, user: discord.Member = None):
    user = user or ctx.author
    invites = await ctx.guild.invites()
    total_invites = sum(map(lambda i: i.uses if i.inviter.id == user.id else 0, invites))
    sing_or_plur = 'members' if total_invites > 0 else 'member'
    user_or_self = "You've" if user == ctx.author else f"{user} has"
    await ctx.send(f"{user_or_self} invited {sing_or_plur} to the server!")
```

Comment: Yes thank you but how would i make a leaderboard command to see the top voters